# IIS Web.Config Custom 404 errors

Tags: iis, web-config

I'm pretty much tearing my hair out with this, something which seems so easy.

Looking to implement a custom 404 error page and here's my code - simple it would seem, but it just doesn't work - any ideas.

Before anyone down rates this, I've tried almost every thread around but the same thing happens, or actually doesn't.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
<remove statusCode="404" />
<error statusCode="404" path="/errors/e404.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

WITHOUT this code, I get the standard Windows error message.

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, 
or is temporarily unavailable.
```

WITH this code, I get a different error - but not my custom page. So something is happening, just not what I want. Any ideas or pointers would be much appreciated.

```
This localhost page can’t be found No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost
```

Comment: have you tried this [one](https://forums.asp.net/t/1317222.aspx?Custom+404+error+setting+in+web+config+only+working+for+aspx+pages+in+IIS7)?

Comment: Thanks - no dice :(

Comment: What else can you tell us about your site/app?  What technologies are in play?  What is the URL that you are requesting to produce that error?   Also, what version of IIS (or OS) are you on?

Comment: It's sitting on a Windows box, so IIS - dev box is Windows 10 but will ultimately sit on Server  2012R2.  My URL is : https://localhost/mercury/Test123 (which doesn't exist) -

Comment: okay, can you tell us where your errors folder is located? it has to be relative to the server root right? (inetpub/wwwroot/errors)?

Comment: Its safe to assume you're not using MVC, ASP.NET, PHP, etc?

Comment: use `<error statusCode="404" path="/mercury/errors/e404.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />` and review your [setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/error)

Comment: I've tried that too, and every combination    /localhost/mercury/

Comment: How are your sites/applications configured?  Is your site pointing directly at c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mercury\?

Comment: The physical path of the folder i'm working in is outside of the inetpub folder - but resolves perfectly well.   C:\Users\Me\Documents\WebSites\Mercury - but this isn't the server path, that would be //localhost/mercury/.  Everything that I've read says that the error path should be relative to the root, which should be /localhost/mercury/errors/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/error `ExecuteURL` uses relative path, which means you need to calculate the absolutely path out yourself, but throughout your question and comments, you didn't show enough for others to help. If possible, switch to `Redirect` and set an absolute URL, which should be a lot easier to set (you don't need to calculate any more).

Comment: Are you using IIS Express and/or Visual Studio?

Comment: @LexLi - thanks, it was not my intention to be brief but your suggestion to use a redirect with absolute URL worked - mucho !!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is almost certainly that because you used "ExecuteURL" and its simply not finding it.  I was able to reproduce the issue you have by using IIS Express and Visual Studio 2017.  To troubleshoot run ProcMon from Sysinternals (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and do a search for the file you are searching for (Test123) and also the Error File you are expecting (e404.asp).

It is important to note (as others have said) that when using ExecuteURL, it must be a relative path **to the site**, not the App or VDir.   VS & IISExpress handle much of those details behind the scenes so can make it more difficult to determine what level is the Site/App/VDir/etc.

Comment: And `Redirect` is always easier to configure properly, as it only asks for an absolute URL.